# Hyperlinks delayed in working?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, jquery

[This page is using jQuery](http://www.invisiblewebdesign.co.uk/temp/silver/) to modify the links and then perform the page slide.

If you click on the 'Next' button a couple of times,  then try to click the 'Prev' button, it does not do anything until you click the 'Prev' button around 3 times.

Can anyone suggest a reason why and how to make it instant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you're changing the `href` in the `click` event, if you want to navigate to these, you need to change it in something earlier, say `mousedown`, like this:

```
$(function () {
    $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'x';
    $.localScroll({offset:-250});

    var LinkCounter = 0;
    $('#prev').mousedown(function(){    
        PrevCounter = LinkCounter--;
        this.href='#box' + LinkCounter;
        $('#next').attr({href: '#box' + PrevCounter});        
    });
    $('#next').mousedown(function(){    
        PrevCounter = LinkCounter++;
        this.href='#box' + LinkCounter;
        $('#prev').attr({href: '#box' + PrevCounter});                

    });
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vrxkF/1/) - or [test a full screen version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vrxkF/1/embedded/result,js,html/).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing jquery version to latest to match other jquery elements.

is the cufon affecting the links ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not especially familiar with the ScrollTo plugin, but have you tried modifying the click functions to `return false` at the end?